# VBA Excel Connection Refresh - Runtime 91 Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to refresh one connection (of four) that feeds a pivot.  The other three connections are relatively static and do not require regular refreshing.  I used the recorder to create the following, but when it runs I get "Run-Time Error 91" at the first Selection line.  I've searched several forums but can't find anything that exactly matches.  Any suggestions?

---

```
Sub RefreshPareto()
'
' RefreshPareto Macro
'
Sheets("Paretos").Select
Selection.ListObject.TableObject.Refresh
Selection.ListObject.TableObject.Refresh
ActiveWorkbook.Connections( _
    "WorksheetConnection_Work Order Tracker.xlsx!Tracker").Refresh

' Add date stamp

Range("C30").Value = Now()

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some links to other VBA Runtime Error 91 questions on this site?  I don't know VBA but it looks from other questions like the general solution to error 91 is to explicitly `Set` the object to a variable first.

Comment: That's exactly the trouble...I can see that I need to add a variable, but I have no idea what variable to add or what to set it to.  I tried adding an object variable and setting it with the sheet range of the Pivot that needed refreshing, but the same runtime error appeared at the same line as before.